# ^C no longer sends SIGINT

Tags: linux

^C no longer issues a sigint in any application I've tried. I'm using ArchLinux. This is highly bad and I need it fixed. All help appreciated.

EDIT: So, we've found that ^C is sending a SIGINT, but most things are ignoring it. This problem only exists within X; ^C on a real tty seems to be honored as expected. VLC responds to ^C within X, but I can't find anything else which does. A manual SIGINT via kill -2 seems to be ignored, too.

There are ongoing discussions on this issue at http://bugs.archlinux.org/task/17817 and http://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=88645 .

Comment: Are you on the local console, or connected in via ssh? If via ssh, what are you using as your local terminal?

Comment: I am on the local console.

Answer (score 4):

Try running `stty -a`, that should give you something like:

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 40; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = ;
eol2 = ; swtch = ; ...
```

The field you are interested in is "intr = ^C" (or whatever "intr" is set to for you). That tells you what key combination generates a SIGINT to the process that owns the terminal. To set it back to ^C, you'll need to be able to generate a ^C on the keyboard and the exact mechanism for doing that varies from shell to shell, but some quick testing indicates that for (at least) bash and ksh you do it by first pressing ^V (I have a vague memory that sufficiently old "plain sh" required \^C to insert a literal ^C on the line).

Comment: ^V works in all programs that use the `readline` library, but appears to work in `dash` too.

Comment: Thanks for this. intr = ^C on mine, but we've made some progress. See my edits to the original question.

Comment: Is the terminal set to "brkint" or "-brkint"? Similarly for "-ignbrk" and "ignbrk"?

Comment: Additionally, you can (usually) get a half-decent "cooked IO" terminal by doing `stty sane`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a trap on SIGINT set in your shell?